# Schema.org setup for related products?

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-search-console, microdata

I would like to setup Schema.org markup for related products.

I have tried this code but I have doubt in my mind:

```
itemprop="isRelatedTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"
```

My product page is https://www.amigotrekking.com/everest-base-camp-trek.html

Answer (score 7):

- If it’s a "functionally similar" product, use the [`isSimilarTo`](http://schema.org/isSimilarTo) property.
- If it’s a "consumable" for another product, use the [`isConsumableFor`](http://schema.org/isConsumableFor) property.
- If it’s an "accessory or spare part" for another product, use the [`isAccessoryOrSparePartFor`](http://schema.org/isAccessoryOrSparePartFor) property.
- If it’s a "somehow related" product, use the [`isRelatedTo`](http://schema.org/isRelatedTo) property.

So for a related product, a Microdata example would be:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <aside>
    <article itemprop="isRelatedTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"></article>
  </aside>
</article>
```

Comment: Any reason why you use an '<aside>' here for the 'isRelatedTo'? These isRelatedTo products should be a part of the main flow, isn't it?

Comment: @Ethan: The choice of the HTML element doesn’t affect the Microdata, so this would be a pure semantic HTML question.  It depends on the relation whether or not `aside` is appropriate; it’s appropriate to use `aside` if they are "tangentially related".

Comment: @unor Is there a way to provide a url for the related product? For example, I have a page where I am showing the product details for X1 product. at the very bottom I an using `<aside>` tag with some items that are related to the current one being viewed. Is there a way to point the related product in the aside to the current product being viewed using the Url of the current product being viewed? If a url is not an option, is there a way to do it using some sort of id?

Comment: @Junior: Please ask this as a separate question (showing an example of the HTML context); the comments aren’t the right place this.