# Multiple Schema.org markups on a single page

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

We have several Schema.org items on a single page. For example, a category page has `BreadcrumbList` markup to show navigation *and* `ItemList` markup to show products. A product page has `Product` markup plus `BreadcrumbList` markup and (sometimes) several `ItemList`s (upsells and crossells). `ListItem`s are always `Product` markup.

Some are implemented as `<script type="application/ld+json">` and some are inline markups.

[Structured Data Testing Tools](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) show no error or warning.

All these markups are unrelated (physically) to each other. That is they are not included in a single "*GlobalPage*" markup.

Is it correct to include several markups on a single page?

In fact I used `Microdata` all the time and I think it is more "natural" but after GWT (now Search Console) showed the only "correct" example for product I change it to `ld+json` format (w/out seo improvement). SDTT means nothing. GWT still shows "Start with..." even if everything were 5* for years.

I understand that no *true* answer may exist (*untraceable route of Google*) but I want to hear an **expert opinion** on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it’s fine to describe multiple entities on the same page. But, if possible, you should use properties to relate these entities.

For your examples:

- For a category page, you can use [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) and its properties [`breadcrumb`](http://schema.org/breadcrumb) (for the [`BreadcrumbList`](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) entity) and [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) (for the `ItemList` entitiy that contains the products).
- For a product page, you can use [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) with the same properties, but here the `mainEntity` property references a [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) entitiy as value. Schema.org also defines [properties for related products](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854902/1591669) (but they don’t expect an `ItemList` as value).

If using different syntaxes on the same page (e.g., JSON-LD and Microdata) this becomes harder; you would have to define a URI for each entity (in JSON-LD with `@id`, in Microdata with `itemid`) and reference these URIs as values for the properties. If using only one syntax, you can simply nest the entities.